# How are middlewares executed in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

I'm adding Auth0 to simple project and trying to understand how middlewares work.

In my Startup.cs I have this code

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<AuthSettings> auth0Settings)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    // Add the cookie middleware
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true
    });

    // Add the OIDC middleware
    var options = new OpenIdConnectOptions("Auth0")
    {
        // here there are some configurations
        // .....................
    };

    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("name");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("picture");

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);

    app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
    {
       routeBuilder.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
    });
}
```

If I understand correctly the idea of middleware in ASP.NET Core in our example, if there is a cookie present and authentication can be done by it

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
      AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
      AutomaticChallenge = true
 });
```

OpenId middleware will not be executed.

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
```

Could somebody explain me how does OpenId middleware knows that it should not be executed?

At the bottom we have

```
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
     routeBuilder.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});
```

How does it knows that it should always be executed but in case where we request some static file we do not use mvc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every single middleware in the pipeline can choose to call the next middleware. The reason you get static files instead of it hitting an MVC controller is because the static file middleware finds the file requested, and chooses not to call the next middleware in the chain. It simply returns the file as a response.

`AutomaticAuthenticate` in authentication middleware always means "Inspect the incoming request. If you find something that interests you, create a ClaimsPrincipal from it." In this case cookie authentication automatically creates a principal for the signed-in user when their sign-in cookie is in the request, before passing the request to the next middleware.

The OpenId Connect middleware executes actually, but it doesn't do anything because it won't find anything interesting in the request even if it had `AutomaticAuthenticate = true`. It is looking for requests to its callback path, which by default is set as `CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc");` in the [constructor](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c60d1e1a14691a624f46b350f6561dc752e3964c/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L39).

The two authentication middleware are setup like this so that the cookie middleware runs always, but OpenId Connect only redirects to the identity provider when requested (e.g. by returning a ChallengeResult from your MVC controller).

Comment: Do you have any comment related to the "AutomaticChallenge" property? What effect have AutomaticChallenge set to true in the UseCookieAuthentication middleware? My findings tell me that this property should not be set to true if you have a UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication in the pipeline, this due to the fact that the OIDC middleware by default have AutomaticChallenge set to true.

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/210

Comment: AutomaticChallenge simply defines if the middleware should act as if it had been directly asked to issue a challenge when a request is unauthorized. It's a bit pointless to have two of them since only the one registered closer to the unauthorized result runs (i.e. the one registered later). It really depends on your specific usecase which middleware should be the default one. *Typically* OIDC is the default since we want the user to get redirected to the login provider.